# Do I need to specify a number in front of * if all rows in a row definition are equal size?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm defining rows like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="25*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

As all the numbers are the same is there even any need to add the "25" 
here or could I just specify as "*" ?

How about if I completely remove the RowDefinitions. Will it default to same height for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the . `*25` , if you do this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

All the rows will have the same size. In Xamarin Documentation, they only say that the default value for the Column Width is `*` so we might assume the default value here can also be the star, but not sure. It's better to declare.